# The most efficient query to select min elements from table and date_format displayed

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, min, date-format

I've one table with 1 million of rows and I want to get the rows with min date and formatted by day.

My table is:

```
Id  Created_at          Value
1   2019-04-08 10:35:32 254
1   2019-04-08 10:31:23 241
1   2019-04-08 11:47:32 258
2   2019-04-08 10:32:42 276
2   2019-04-08 10:34:23 280
2   2019-04-08 11:34:23 290
```

And I would like to get (the min created_at values for each hour and format by hour):

```
Id  Created_at          Value
1   2019-04-08 10:00:00 241
1   2019-04-08 11:00:00 258
2   2019-04-08 10:00:00 276
2   2019-04-08 11:00:00 290
```

I have mysql 5.7 so I can't build windowed queries. I'm researching the most efficient way to select this elements.

Comment: Why do you want  `258`? That not the minimum value.

Comment: Oups, I want the most recent value for each hour

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 5.7

You can use a join on subquery for min result

```
select  m.id, date(m.created_at) , m.value
INNER JOIN (
select  min(created_at) min_date
from  my_tbale  
group by date(created_at),hour(created_at)

) t on t.min_date  = m.created_at
```

be sure you have a composite index  on my_table columns (created_at, id, value)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
select
  t.id, m.h, t.value
from my_table t
join (
  select
    id,
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(created_at) / 3600) * 3600) as h,
    min(created_at) as min_created_at
  from my_table
  group by id, from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(created_at) / 3600) * 3600)
) m on m.id = t.id and m.min_created_at = t.created_at
```